# C# MVC - SP not insert values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make an insert from my controller to my database. I already debug and it never enter on the exception. But i can not see the values on the db.

This is my sp:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterUser]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Username nvarchar(10),
@Password nvarchar(10),
@Mail nvarchar(10),
@Birthday date

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO Users
(
    Username,
    Pass,
    Mail,
    Birthday
)

VALUES 
(
    @Username,
    @Password,
    @Mail,
    @Birthday
)

END
```

And on my model i used this method:

```
public bool registerUser(UserModel user)
    {
        bool isOk = false;

        using (SqlConnection connection = DbConnection.OpenConnection2())
        {
            try
            {

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RegisterUser", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);

                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = user.userName.Trim();
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = user.password.Trim();
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mail", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = user.mail.Trim();


                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    isOk = true;
                }
        }
    }
return isOk;
}
```

Any ideas of why this is not working?

Thanks

Comment: You have a required parameter in your stored procedure (@Birthday date) but you are not supplying it. That may be causing the problem.

Comment: How is defined your Users table?, Does birthday attribute has default value?

Comment: Birthday is allow for null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are easy, if you use exception handling in a proper manner. You are swallowing the exception thrown by Ado.net. Follow these steps for solving your problem:

- First of all you should add a `throw` statement in your `catch` block to get the exception being thrown. In production, You should catch that at later calling function or layer.
- You need to provide all the parameters to your stored procedure. Currently, You are not passing one parameter named @Birthday and its value. Add this parameter with its value.

Here is the modified code that should work.

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                  
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = user.userName.Trim();
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = user.password.Trim();
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mail", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = user.mail.Trim();
//Assuming that the user object has a field named Birthday
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Birthday", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = user.Birthday; 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you follow my first advice, you will nearly get any other problem that is occurring in your code.

I hope it will help you somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use the throw and I saw the message error. I trace the query and the problem was that the exec was repeating twice the values. So it throws Procedure or function has too many arguments specified. So with the throw and your code.. now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not supplying "@Birthday" parameter, Please specify "@Birthday date" as "@Birthday date = NULL" in the stored procedure as below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterUser]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Username nvarchar(10),
@Password nvarchar(10),
@Mail nvarchar(10),
@Birthday date = NULL

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO Users
(
    Username,
    Pass,
    Mail,
    Birthday
)

VALUES 
(
    @Username,
    @Password,
    @Mail,
    @Birthday
)

END
```

Rest of your code looks all good to me.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, you can provide a default value for the parameter @Birthday as:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterUser]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Username nvarchar(10),
@Password nvarchar(10),
@Mail nvarchar(10),
@Birthday date = NULL

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO Users
(
    Username,
    Pass,
    Mail,
    Birthday
)

VALUES 
(
    @Username,
    @Password,
    @Mail,
    @Birthday
)

END
```